# Label Values and Total in Google Visualization Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am trying to display the value of each bar and then the total value of all bars in a stacked bar chart The problem is, I get the last bar's value and the total both outside the bar.  If I do not show the total, I get the value inside the bar.  Using the code below the the last two annotations are outside the second bar even when the second bar is long enough to show its label.
[image: Full Code - this is close]

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

         <h3>Registrations</h3>
         <div id="registrations_chart"></div>

  </body>
</html>
<script>
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'bar', 'gauge', 'table']});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStackedBar);

function drawStackedBar() {

  var myHeight = 350;
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Registrations');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Regular');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Work Study');

  data.addRows([
    ['Adult', 20, 12],
    ['Teen', 3, 0]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0,
    1, {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
      return dt.getValue(row, 1);
    },
    type: "number",
    role: "annotation"
    },
    2, {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
      return dt.getValue(row, 2);
    },
    type: "number",
    role: "annotation"
    },
    // series 1
    {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
      return dt.getValue(row, 1) + dt.getValue(row, 2);
    },
    type: "number",
    role: "annotation"
    }
  ]);


  var options = {
    animation:{
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'out',
      startup: true
    },
    title: 'Registrations',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    height: myHeight, width: 500,
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      maxLines: 3
    },
    bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
    isStacked: true
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('registrations_chart'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
</script>
```

If I removed the last option in the setColumns to make that section read as follows:

```
  view.setColumns([0,
    1, {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
      return dt.getValue(row, 1);
    },
    type: "number",
    role: "annotation"
    },
    2, {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
      return dt.getValue(row, 2);
    },
    type: "number",
    role: "annotation"
    },
    // series 1
    {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
      return dt.getValue(row, 1) + dt.getValue(row, 2);
    },
    type: "number",
    role: "annotation"
    }
  ]);
```

I get the labels where I want them without the Total, as shown below
[image]

What I am after is to add the Total to the end and the Labels consistently inside as shown below:
[image]

I have tried too many methods to remember or list here, but am not getting the Total at the end.  How can I get this last Label to appear and keep the others inside the bar when they will fit there? Note that I have made the red bar longer than the blue one and the numbers still displayed as shown.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you could add another series column for the total

then hide it from the chart with the following options...

```
    enableInteractivity: false,
    tooltip: "none",
    visibleInLegend: false
```

this will allow the annotations from the other values to perform normally

the total annotation will always show outside,
but need to adjust a few options to keep it from overwriting others...

```
    annotations: {
      stem: {
        color: "transparent",
        length: 28
      },
      textStyle: {
        color: "#000000",
      }
    },
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('50', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var myHeight = 350;
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Registrations');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Regular');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Work Study');

  data.addRows([
    ['Adult', 20, 12],
    ['Teen', 3, 0]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0,
    1, {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getValue(row, 1);
      },
      type: "number",
      role: "annotation"
    },
    2, {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getValue(row, 2);
      },
      type: "number",
      role: "annotation"
    },
    {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return 0;
      },
      label: "Total",
      type: "number",
    },
    {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getValue(row, 1) + dt.getValue(row, 2);
      },
      type: "number",
      role: "annotation"
    }
  ]);


  var options = {
    animation:{
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'out',
      startup: true
    },
    title: 'Registrations',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    height: myHeight, width: 500,
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      maxLines: 3
    },
    bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
    isStacked: true,
    series: {
      2: {
        annotations: {
          stem: {
            color: "transparent",
            length: 28
          },
          textStyle: {
            color: "#000000",
          }
        },
        enableInteractivity: false,
        tooltip: "none",
        visibleInLegend: false
      }
    }
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('registrations_chart'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="registrations_chart"></div>
```

**EDIT**

there are no standard options for annotation position
but you can move them manually, once the chart's `'ready'` event fires
or in this case, the `'animationfinish'` event

see following working snippet,
the total annotations are moved down...

```js
google.charts.load('50', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var myHeight = 350;
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Registrations');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Regular');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Work Study');

  data.addRows([
    ['Adult', 20, 12],
    ['Teen', 3, 0]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0,
    1, {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getValue(row, 1);
      },
      type: "number",
      role: "annotation"
    },
    2, {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getValue(row, 2);
      },
      type: "number",
      role: "annotation"
    },
    {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return 0;
      },
      label: "Total",
      type: "number",
    },
    {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getValue(row, 1) + dt.getValue(row, 2);
      },
      type: "number",
      role: "annotation"
    }
  ]);


  var options = {
    animation:{
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'out',
      startup: true
    },
    title: 'Registrations',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    height: myHeight, width: 500,
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      maxLines: 3
    },
    bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
    isStacked: true,
    series: {
      2: {
        annotations: {
          stem: {
            color: "transparent",
          },
          textStyle: {
            color: "#000000",
          }
        },
        enableInteractivity: false,
        tooltip: "none",
        visibleInLegend: false
      }
    }
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('registrations_chart'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'animationfinish', function () {
    $('#registrations_chart text[fill="#000000"]').each(function (index, annotation) {
      if (!isNaN(parseFloat(annotation.textContent))) {
        var yCoord = parseFloat($(annotation).attr('y'));
        $(annotation).attr('y', yCoord + 18);
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(view, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="registrations_chart"></div>
```

Comment: This is great.  Thank you!  One thing: Is there any way to move the label for the Total down?  The first image I have shows the two labels stacked so it is happening at some point.  Maybe even by adding a line feed to the beginning of the label? I tried adding a \n and \r\n and String.fromCharCode(10) (and 12 and 13)  but none of these worked even if  ha other text in the label.  Or possibly not make the stem transparent and include a larger space between the end of the stem and the Total's text?

Comment: there are no standard options for the changes you suggest, but you can manually change the chart elements, see __EDIT__ above...

Comment: WOW!  Beautiful!  Thank you!

Comment: This is a great solution.  Thank you so much

Comment: @WhiteHat, is there a way to change to FontSize and Text Color of the "Total" series that is being added?

Comment: yes, see option above for `annotations.textStyle`, you can change the option for `color` and add option for `fontSize`...

Comment: got it.  Thanks again!

Comment: sure, just keep in mind, if you change the color of the "total" annotations, you will also need to change the color used to find the "total" annotations in order to move them in the `'animationfinish'` event --> `$('#registrations_chart text[fill="#000000"]')` <-- also, the "find" color will need to be all lowercase (not necessary for black obviously `#000000`)

Comment: @WhiteHat, your return type for Total is "number".  Is there a way to convert it to a string? Here is the reason why:  I have the 'var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat' where I convert to annotation to "short", "string", like 2K, 3K...etc for columns 1,2,3.  Now, I added your code for column 4 for Total, which works perfect, but it shows like 8,000 instead, but stacked data is in "short" format.  I don't want to divide the Total by 1000 to get the "K" because if value is 2 million the short will be 2M.  I am very new to Google charts.  Thanks again for being very helpful.

Comment: yes, annotations should be string, just copied from the question, you can do something like --> `return formatter.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 1) + dt.getValue(row, 2));`