# Google Visualization - annotations position

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm using Google visualization stacked bars chart to show a lot of information of my process.

I am trying to do three things necessary to correctly display information.

1) Show the total at the top of the column;
2) When the total value of the column does not fit in the bar, it is next to it, allowing the reading of all items.
3) Display a companion line that will show the total of impacted records (not present in the chart currently)

My necessity:
[image]
I have "L. ratio" for each column, bur the value isn't in the chart.

What I've Done:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStacked);

function drawStacked() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'week');
      data.addColumn('number', 'L0');
      data.addColumn('number', 'L1');
      data.addColumn('number', 'L2');
      data.addColumn('number', 'L3');
      data.addColumn('number', 'L4');
      data.addColumn('number', 'L5');

      data.addRows([
        ['W1', 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ['W2', 75, 60, 20, 0, 0, 0],
        ['W3', 133, 90, 35, 21, 0, 0],
        ['W4', 95, 110, 23, 28, 13, 2],
        ['W5', 83, 80, 60, 40, 20, 15]
        /*[{v: [12, 0, 0], f: '12 pm'}, 5, 2.25],
        [{v: [13, 0, 0], f: '1 pm'}, 6, 3],
        [{v: [14, 0, 0], f: '2 pm'}, 7, 4],
        [{v: [15, 0, 0], f: '3 pm'}, 8, 5.25],
        [{v: [16, 0, 0], f: '4 pm'}, 9, 7.5],
        [{v: [17, 0, 0], f: '5 pm'}, 10, 10],*/
      ]);
      
      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      
      view.setColumns([0,
        1, {
          calc: function (dt, row) {
            return dt.getValue(row, 1);
          },
          type: "number",
          role: "annotation"
        },
        2, {
          calc: function (dt, row) {
            return dt.getValue(row, 2);
          },
          type: "number",
          role: "annotation"
        },
        3, {
          calc: function (dt, row) {
            return dt.getValue(row, 3);
          },
          type: "number",
          role: "annotation"
        },
        4, {
          calc: function (dt, row) {
            return dt.getValue(row, 4);
          },
          type: "number",
          role: "annotation"
        },
        5, {
          calc: function (dt, row) {
            return dt.getValue(row, 5);
          },
          type: "number",
          role: "annotation"
        },
        6, {
          calc: function (dt, row) {
            return dt.getValue(row, 5);
          },
          type: "number",
          role: "annotation"
        },
        {
          calc: function (dt, row) {
            return 0;
          },
          label: "Total",
          type: "number",
        },
        {
          calc: function (dt, row) {
            return dt.getValue(row, 1) + dt.getValue(row, 2) + 
                 dt.getValue(row, 3) + dt.getValue(row, 4) + 
                   dt.getValue(row, 5);
          },
          type: "number",
          role: "annotation"
        }
      ]);

      var options = {
        //title: 'Motivation and Energy Level Throughout the Day',
        animation:{
          duration: 1000,
          easing: 'out',
          startup: true
        },
        legend: {
          position: 'rigth'
          //maxLines: 3
        },
        series: {
          6: {
            annotations: {
            alwaysOutside: true,
              stem: {
                color: "transparent",
              },
              textStyle: {
                color: "#000000",
              }
            },
            enableInteractivity: true,
            tooltip: "none",
            visibleInLegend: false,
            axisTitlesPosition: 'in'
          }
        },
        isStacked: true,
        vAxis: {
          //title: 'Rating (scale of 1-10)',
          viewWindow: {
            max: 600
          }
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(view, options);
    };
```

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: the only config option for annotation position is `stem.length`, which means you can only move it vertically, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39771794/5090771) -- if you need to move them horizontally, you need to do so manually, on the chart's `'ready'` event, [see last snippet in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47166580/5090771) <-- note: last example is for a bar chart, change x instead of y...

Comment: Ok. Thaks. Some idea of ​​how to create a line for the Ratio values?

Comment: add another column to the data table and change the series type in the chart options...